# Rust: How to short-circuit exit from a chain of iterator methods on first Err or None?

Tags: rust, iterator, monads, short-circuiting

Consider a chain of iterator methods:

```rust
.iter().a().b().c()
```

where `a` produces values of type `Option` (or `Result`). Is there a way to have the whole chain return `None` (or (`Err(_)`) as soon as `a` yields a `None` (or `Err(_)`)?

### Detailed example

Given functions `valid` (identifying nonsensical input) and `accept` (an
arbitrary selection criterion):

```rust
type T = u8;
type ERR = u8;

fn valid(x: &T) -> Result<T, ERR> {
    if *x < 10 { Ok(*x) } else { Err(*x) }
}

fn accept(x: &T) -> bool {
    if *x > 9 { panic!("{} should have been rejected by validator")  }
    *x % 2 == 0
}
```

I would like to write a function

```rust
fn count_accepted(data: &[T]) -> Result<usize, ERR>
```

which

- Returns `Err(ERR)` as soon as the first invalid element is encountered in the
  input data
- If all elements are valid, returns `Ok(usize)` containing the count of values
  that satisfied the `accept` criterion

Here is a solution that uses a loop:

```rust
fn count_loop(data: &[T]) -> Result<usize, ERR> {
    let mut count = 0;
    for item in data {
        valid(&item)?;
        if accept(&item) { count += 1 }
    }
    Ok(count)
}
```

which seems to work as required, as witnessed by these tests:

```rust
macro_rules! testem {
    ($count:path) => {
        #[test] fn empty()                 { assert_eq!($count(&[])           , Ok(0)) }
        #[test] fn all_ok_and_accepted()   { assert_eq!($count(&[2,6])        , Ok(2)) }
        #[test] fn all_ok_some_rejected()  { assert_eq!($count(&[2,3])        , Ok(1)) }
        #[test] fn one_invalid()           { assert_eq!($count(&[12])         , Err(12)) }
        #[test] fn stop_on_first_invalid() { assert_eq!($count(&[2,13,6,12,5]), Err(13)) }
    }
}

mod test_loop {testem!{super::count_loop}}
```

I would like to understand whether/how one could implement this behaviour using
iterators rather than a loop.

Consider a related, but simpler problem: if any of the data are not valid, bail
out immediately, otherwise collect all the data into a vector. In other words,
remove the `accept` condition from the previous problem.

This problem has quite a satisfactory solution, because the `FromIterator`
implementation of `Result` takes care of early termination:

```rust
fn related(data: &[T]) -> Result<Vec<T>, ERR> {
    data.iter()
        .map(valid)
        .collect()
}

mod test_related {
    #[test]
    fn stop_on_first_invalid() { assert_eq!(super::related(&[2,13,6,12,5]), Err(13))}
}
```

Here is an extension of `related` which passes the same tests as `count_loop`:

```rust
fn count_via_vec(data: &[T]) -> Result<usize, ERR> {
     Ok(data
        .iter()
        .map(valid)
        .filter(|x| x.is_err() || accept(&x.unwrap()))
        .collect::<Result<Vec<T>, ERR>>()?
        .len())
}

mod test_vvec {testem!{super::count_via_vec}}
```

However: this solution has a number of drawbacks with respect to `count_loop`:

- The filter condition is very noisy.
- The filtering step still needs to be performed when the first invalid item has
  been identified (unlike in the original loop implementation): the `?` appears
  2 lines later than it should ... if that were meaningful.
- A vector is unnecessarily populated (unless Rust performs some cool
  optimization that I'm, as yet, unaware of), so the space complexity rises from
  O(1) to O(N).

The last point would normally be addressed by replacing
`.collect::<Result<Vec<T>, ERR>>()?.len())` with `.count()`, but this has the
further detrimental effect of removing the recognition of invalid cases: they
are simply counted as successes, as witnessed by the test failed by this
implementation:

```rust
fn count_iterate(data: &[T]) -> Result<usize, ERR> {
    Ok(data
       .iter()
       .map(valid)
       .filter(|x| x.is_err() ||  accept(&x.unwrap()))
       .count())
}

mod test_iter {testem!{super::count_iterate}}
```

Can you suggest some mechanism for early returning in chains of iterator methods
that can be used in cases such as this?

Comment: Have you given the `try_<function>` Iterator methods a try? `try_for_each` seems similar to what you're looking for. https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.try_for_each

Comment: Did you end up finding any clean solution? Thanks!

Comment: I found a couple of things which were a step in the right direction, but as I've been kept away from Rust for a couple of months, memory is very hazy. The first is https://docs.rs/fallible-iterator/0.2.0/fallible_iterator/index.html . The other is that implementations of Error in some circumstances actually do a good job of this doing this quite generally (there might be a discussion of this in some blog post, maybe by Michael Snoyman?) which seemed to be *very* close to what I wanted, but I'm not managing to find it at the moment :-(

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for [`std::iter::Sum`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Sum.html) which has an `impl<T, U, E> Sum<Result<U, E>> for Result<T, E> where T: Sum<U>`, while there are also impls for `Sum` for all basic integers.

So the following will Just Work:

```
fn valid(x: &u32) -> Result<u32, u32> {
    if *x < 10 { Ok(1) } else { Err(*x) }
}

fn count(x: &[u32]) -> Result<u32, u32> {
    x.iter()
     .map(valid)
     .sum()
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", count(&[13,1,2,3]));
}
```

As the docs on `Sum` say, this will short-circuit the iterator if an error is encountered. This will include short-circuiting chained iterators.

Comment: The `Result` implementation for `Sum` is interesting, thanks. However, the need to modify the `valid` criterion would require the use of an adapter, and by then it becomes much uglier than the loop approach. Furthermore, this solution ignores the downstream chain (`.b().c()` in the general example, `filter(accept)` in the specific example) and I don't see how that could be fixed. Even if it can be fixed, it's an ad-hoc solution to one problem in this category, rather than a solution to the problem posed at the top of the question: get it to work for `iter.a::<Result>().b().c()" in general.